# sort command doesn't work as intended on this file

Tags: sort

I'm trying to do a sort command but it doesn't work on this file. I'm not sure why.

```
 sort -n -k+3 employee > hired2
```

The instruction says this should sort the employee based on the month hired.

Here is the file. MM/DD/YEAR for the dates

```
mgt Cooper John     06151995   66000
mgt Davidson Darla  04151992   69500
mgt MacDonald George  06151985 70000
act Smith Thomas  04102002     56000
act Smith Alecia  04121991     65000
mis MacLeod Janice  01021977   90000
mis Mack Joe  02252003         85000
mis Winslow Sarah  02151995    58000
adm Smith Dexter  01021975    100000
mis Benneth Joan  08152001     79000
mgt Neason Elizabeth  10251998 65500
act NeSmith Donald  11301966   99500
```

This is what I get:

```
act NeSmith Donald  11301966    99500
act Smith Alecia    04121991    65000
act Smith Thomas    04102002    56000
adm Smith Dexter    01021975    100000
mgt     Cooper John     06151995    66000
mgt Davidson Darla  04151992    69500
mgt MacDonald George    06151985    70000
mgt Neason Elizabeth    10251998    65500
mis Bennett Joan    08152001    79000
mis Mack Joe    02252003    85000
mis MacLeod Janice  01021977    90000
mis Winslow Sarah   02151995    58000
```

What could possible be wrong? It couldn't be a spacing problem could it?

Comment: This is contrived test data, isn't it? #PrivacyMatters

Comment: Yes its not real

Comment: i see the instructions says sort -n -k+3 emplyee so i guess its a mistake  made by the professor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting by a wrong column. The numbering of columns begins with 1 and the month column is 4th. So try this:

```
sort -n -k+4 employee > hired2
```

Comment: yeah i see the professor said +3 so error on her part ughh confusing instructions now i have to play around for the other parts of the lab cuz it looks wrong as well

Comment: It's either `sort +3` (old style) or `sort -k 4` (POSIX style) to sort on the part of the line that starts with the 4th field (including its leading blanks). Not all `sort` implementations will accept `sort -k +4`. Some will complain about that `+4` not being a valid specification.

Comment: @KatMi - See Stephane's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Some old versions of sort began counting fields at zero, and used the notation +n for the beginning field of a key. Newer versions of sort may accept the obsolete notation, but I have not checked to see if they begin counting at zero. Perhaps the instructor was referring to / is using an old version ... cheers, drl

Comment: It's either `sort +3` (old style) or `sort -k 4` (POSIX style)

Answer (score 0):

> the instruction says this should sort the employee based on the month hired

Which instruction? I get the expected result here using

```
$ sort -n -k 4 <file>
```

based on copy/pasting your test data - this implies that the file contains spaces instead of tabs, if there were any.

Answer (score 0):

If it also should be readable I would align the columns:

```
$ column -t < employee | sort -nk4
adm  Smith      Dexter     01021975  100000
mis  MacLeod    Janice     01021977  90000
mis  Winslow    Sarah      02151995  58000
mis  Mack       Joe        02252003  85000
act  Smith      Thomas     04102002  56000
act  Smith      Alecia     04121991  65000
mgt  Davidson   Darla      04151992  69500
mgt  MacDonald  George     06151985  70000
mgt  Cooper     John       06151995  66000
mis  Benneth    Joan       08152001  79000
mgt  Neason     Elizabeth  10251998  65500
act  NeSmith    Donald     11301966  99500
```